# Mixed content blocking in chrome cast receiver app

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, drm, mixed-content, custom-receiver

I am trying to play a DRM protected content using Chromecast custom receiver. I am following this doc https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver.

But it is not working for me. It gives the following error log.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://abcdefgfgh/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mytestvideo’. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the log there is descriptive enough as to what it means. You need to have all your video content to be served over https (SSL should be signed by a known authority, not a self-signed one) and the server also has to provide the appropriate CORS headers. Please address those and see if that helps or not. As a side note, you might want to grab our [reference receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer) as your starting point; it already does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: we are new in chrome cast receiver side . We hosted a sample receiver app in AWS s3 bucket. while casting a http video content we are getting following error 
media_player.js:33 [ 30.353s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.MEDIAKEYS/203 (NotSupportedError: Only secure origins are allowed 
But when we use a https video content it is working fine. Can you please provide any input ?

Comment: If you are using any type pf adaptive rate streams or DRM, your content needs to be streamed over https.